# In Tensorflow, get the names of all the Tensors in a graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, skflow

I am creating neural nets with `Tensorflow` and `skflow`; for some reason I want to get the values of some inner tensors for a given input, so I am using `myClassifier.get_layer_value(input, "tensorName")`, `myClassifier` being a `skflow.estimators.TensorFlowEstimator`.

However, I find it difficult to find the correct syntax of the tensor name, even knowing its name (and I'm getting confused between operation and tensors), so I'm using tensorboard to plot the graph and look for the name.

Is there a way to enumerate all the tensors in a graph without using tensorboard?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You can do

```
[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

Also, if you are prototyping in an IPython notebook, you can show the graph directly in notebook, see `show_graph` function in Alexander's Deep Dream [notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/deepdream/deepdream.ipynb)

Comment: You can filter this for e.g. variables by adding `if "Variable" in n.op` at the end of the comprehension.

Comment: Is there a way to get  a specific node if you know the name?

Comment: To read more about graph nodes: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/#nodes

Comment: The command above yields the names of all operations/nodes. To get the names of all tensors, do: tensors_per_node = [node.values() for node in graph.get_operations()]
tensor_names = [tensor.name for tensors in tensors_per_node for tensor in tensors]

Answer (score 42):

I'll try to summarize the answers:

**To get all *nodes* in the graph:** (type `tensorflow.core.framework.node_def_pb2.NodeDef`)

```python
all_nodes = [n for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

**To get all *ops* in the graph:** (type `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation`)

```python
all_ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
```

**To get all *variables* in the graph:** (type `tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable`)

```python
all_vars = tf.global_variables()
```

**To get all *tensors* in the graph:** (type `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`)

```python
all_tensors = [tensor for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() for tensor in op.values()]
```

**To get all *placeholders* in the graph:** (type `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`)

```python
all_placeholders = [placeholder for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() if op.type=='Placeholder' for placeholder in op.values()]
```

***Tensorflow 2***

To get the graph in Tensorflow 2, instead of `tf.get_default_graph()` you need to instantiate a `tf.function` first and access the `graph` attribute, for example:

```python
graph = func.get_concrete_function().graph
```

where `func` is a `tf.function`

Comment: Heads up for that TF2 version!

Answer (score 25):

There is a way to do it slightly faster than in Yaroslav's answer by using [get_operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures). Here is a quick example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(1.3, name='const_a')
b = tf.Variable(3.1, name='variable_b')
c = tf.add(a, b, name='addition')
d = tf.multiply(c, a, name='multiply')

for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
    print(str(op.name))
```

Comment: You cannot get Tensors using `tf.get_operations()`. Only operation you can get.

Comment: @Soulduck you can get the Tensors for each operation using `op.values()`, for example:
`last_tensor = graph.get_operations()[-1].values()`
where `graph.get_operations()[-1]` is the last operation in the graph.

Answer (score 11):

`tf.all_variables()` can get you the information you want.

Also, [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/3f1941853f8703cbf1005c04f76f75bc609fcfc9) made today in TensorFlow Learn that provides a function `get_variable_names` in estimator that you can use to retrieve all variable names easily.

Comment: This function is deprecated

Comment: ... and its successor is `tf.global_variables()`

Comment: this fetches only variables, not tensors.

Comment: In Tensorflow 1.9.0 shows that `all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02`

Comment: `module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'all_variables'`

Answer (score 5):

I think this will do too:

```
print(tf.contrib.graph_editor.get_tensors(tf.get_default_graph()))
```

But compared with Salvado and Yaroslav's answers, I don't know which one is better.

Comment: This one worked with a graph imported from a frozen_inference_graph.pb file used in the tensorflow object detection API. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer only gives you a list of strings with the names. I prefer a different approach, which gives you (almost) direct access to the tensors:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
list_of_tuples = [op.values() for op in graph.get_operations()]
```

`list_of_tuples` now contains every tensor, each within a tuple. You could also adapt it to get the tensors directly:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
list_of_tuples = [op.values()[0] for op in graph.get_operations()]
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the OP asked for the list of the tensors instead of the list of operations/nodes, the code should be slightly different:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()    
tensors_per_node = [node.values() for node in graph.get_operations()]
tensor_names = [tensor.name for tensors in tensors_per_node for tensor in tensors]
```

Answer (score 3):

Previous answers are good, I'd just like to share a utility function I wrote to select Tensors from a graph:

```
def get_graph_op(graph, and_conds=None, op='and', or_conds=None):
    """Selects nodes' names in the graph if:
    - The name contains all items in and_conds
    - OR/AND depending on op
    - The name contains any item in or_conds

    Condition starting with a "!" are negated.
    Returns all ops if no optional arguments is given.

    Args:
        graph (tf.Graph): The graph containing sought tensors
        and_conds (list(str)), optional): Defaults to None.
            "and" conditions
        op (str, optional): Defaults to 'and'. 
            How to link the and_conds and or_conds:
            with an 'and' or an 'or'
        or_conds (list(str), optional): Defaults to None.
            "or conditions"

    Returns:
        list(str): list of relevant tensor names
    """
    assert op in {'and', 'or'}

    if and_conds is None:
        and_conds = ['']
    if or_conds is None:
        or_conds = ['']

    node_names = [n.name for n in graph.as_graph_def().node]

    ands = {
        n for n in node_names
        if all(
            cond in n if '!' not in cond
            else cond[1:] not in n
            for cond in and_conds
        )}

    ors = {
        n for n in node_names
        if any(
            cond in n if '!' not in cond
            else cond[1:] not in n
            for cond in or_conds
        )}

    if op == 'and':
        return [
            n for n in node_names
            if n in ands.intersection(ors)
        ]
    elif op == 'or':
        return [
            n for n in node_names
            if n in ands.union(ors)
        ]
```

So if you have a graph with ops:

```
['model/classifier/dense/kernel',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel/Assign',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel/read',
'model/classifier/dense/bias',
'model/classifier/dense/bias/Assign',
'model/classifier/dense/bias/read',
'model/classifier/dense/MatMul',
'model/classifier/dense/BiasAdd',
'model/classifier/ArgMax/dimension',
'model/classifier/ArgMax']
```

Then running

```
get_graph_op(tf.get_default_graph(), ['dense', '!kernel'], 'or', ['Assign'])
```

returns:

```
['model/classifier/dense/kernel/Assign',
'model/classifier/dense/bias',
'model/classifier/dense/bias/Assign',
'model/classifier/dense/bias/read',
'model/classifier/dense/MatMul',
'model/classifier/dense/BiasAdd']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works for me in TensorFlow 2.3 -

```py
def load_pb(path_to_pb):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(path_to_pb, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        return graph
```

```
tf_graph = load_pb(MODEL_FILE)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf_graph)

# Show tensor names in graph
for op in tf_graph.get_operations():
    print(op.values())
```

where `MODEL_FILE` is the path to your frozen graph.

Taken from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/converting-a-simple-deep-learning-model-from-pytorch-to-tensorflow-b6b353351f5d).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
    print('\n',n)
```