# While debugging, how to print all variables (which is in list format) who are trainable in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

While debugging, how to print all variables (which is in list format) who are trainable in Tensorflow?

For instance,

```
    tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
```

I want to check all the variables in tvars (which is list type).

I've already tried the below code which returns error,

```
    myvars = session.run([tvars])
    print(myvars)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what error you are getting?!

Comment: print([v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()])

Answer (score 15):

Since `tf.trainable_variables()` returns a list of `tf.Variable` objects, you should be able to pass its result straight to `Session.run()`:

```
tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
tvars_vals = sess.run(tvars)

for var, val in zip(tvars, tvars_vals):
    print(var.name, val)  # Prints the name of the variable alongside its value.
```

Answer (score 5):

To print the complete list of all all variables or nodes of a tensor-flow graph, you may try this:

```
[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

I copied this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883949/in-tensorflow-get-the-names-of-all-the-tensors-in-a-graph/36893840).