# Get value of constant node in tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow

I am using `tf.Estimator` to create my model. This is training for a while, and then does `estimator.export_savedmodel`. Since I use dropout for training, I'm afraid that doing the export straight after training will apply dropout when doing predictions.

Now all I have is a model loaded with `tf.saved_model.loader.load`. I figured I can get the graph definition from the session in which I am loading the model. Can I check the value of dropout here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out you can check values of any variables or constants in the graph. After all, that is the purpose of exporting a model.

You should have access to the session in which the model was loaded. 
In this case, you can go through all the nodes in the graph, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36893840/786559) and extract the one corresponding to the dropout value. If you didn't give it a specific name, this will default to something like `name_space/dropout/keep_prob`.

```
dropout_nodes = [node for node in sess.graph_def.node if 'dropout' in node.name]
```

Then, you can inspect the value of any such node. In my case, it looks like this:

```
name: "deep_bidirectional_lstm/dropout/keep_prob"
op: "Const"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "value"
  value {
    tensor {
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      tensor_shape {
      }
      float_val: 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

This is a protobuf message. It says the operation is a `"Const"` and its value is a `tensor` of type `DT_FLOAT`, with no shape, and value `1.0`

You can use the protobuf API to parse this into a dictionary, or if want just the last part, you can extract it like so:

```
print(dropout_nodes[0].attr.get('value').tensor.float_val[0])
1.0
```

So you are safe, your dropout is 1 :)

---

Coming back to this about 1 year later, I realise there is a point of confusion: when you say `.attr.get('value')`, the `'value'` refers to which of the two attributes to get, based on their `key`: `"dtype"`, or `"value"`. It has nothing to do with the `value` property of each attribute.