# 'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])

Tags: python, django, image-processing, tensorflow

I have retrained the model using this [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/r0.1/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py). Then followed instruction from this [repo](https://github.com/ccd97/image-classify-server) after cloning. Replaced newly generated **labels.txt** and **graph.pb** file. When posting an image to classify using the following code ,

```
MAX_K = 10

TF_GRAPH = "{base_path}/inception_model/graph.pb".format(
    base_path=os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
TF_LABELS = "{base_path}/inception_model/labels.txt".format(
    base_path=os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))


def load_graph():
    sess = tf.Session()
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(TF_GRAPH, 'rb') as tf_graph:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(tf_graph.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in tf.gfile.GFile(TF_LABELS)]
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
    return sess, softmax_tensor, label_lines


SESS, GRAPH_TENSOR, LABELS = load_graph()


@csrf_exempt
def classify_api(request):
    data = {"success": False}

    if request.method == "POST":
        tmp_f = NamedTemporaryFile()

    if request.FILES.get("image", None) is not None:
        image_request = request.FILES["image"]
        image_bytes = image_request.read()
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
        image.save(tmp_f, image.format)
    elif request.POST.get("image64", None) is not None:
        base64_data = request.POST.get("image64", None).split(',', 1)[1]
        plain_data = b64decode(base64_data)
        tmp_f.write(plain_data)

    classify_result = tf_classify(tmp_f, int(request.POST.get('k', MAX_K)))
    tmp_f.close()

    if classify_result:
        data["success"] = True
        data["confidence"] = {}
        for res in classify_result:
            data["confidence"][res[0]] = float(res[1])

return JsonResponse(data)


def tf_classify(image_file, k=MAX_K):
    result = list()

    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_file.name, 'rb').read()

    predictions = SESS.run(GRAPH_TENSOR, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
    predictions = predictions[0][:len(LABELS)]
    top_k = predictions.argsort()[-k:][::-1]
    for node_id in top_k:
        label_string = LABELS[node_id]
        score = predictions[node_id]
        result.append([label_string, score])

    return result
```

then it shows the following error.

**TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'DecodeJpeg/contents', does not exist in the graph.**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on this line:

```
predictions = SESS.run(GRAPH_TENSOR, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
```

The key in the `feed_dict` dictionary should be a tensor, not a string. You can look up the tensor by name first:

```
data_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('DecodeJpeg/contents:0')
predictions = SESS.run(GRAPH_TENSOR, {data_tensor: image_data})
```

Comment: Check the name of all tensors, make sure it's here, here's a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883949/in-tensorflow-get-the-names-of-all-the-tensors-in-a-graph

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tensorflow.keras, then you can do the following, but if you are using Keras(but not tensorflow.keras), then try the method for Keras like everyone mentioned above. but the same procedure applies thought.

```py
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
```

put in the place every time you re-use the model.