# KeyError: 'conv4_2' while finding the loss in style loss function and content loss function

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

While coding for " Neural Style Transfer by using Pytorch (Deep Learning) " I was trying to find Content Loss and Style Loss but during the implementation of the code I came across a KeyError: 'conv4_2' which I was not able to solve.

please have a look at the code below :

```
# Get content, style features and create gram matrix 

def get_features(image,model):

  layers = { 
      '0' : 'conv1_1',
      '5' : 'conv2_1',
      '10' : 'conv3_1',
      '19' : 'conv4_1',
      '21' : 'conv4_2', # content_feature
      '28' : 'conv5_1'

  }

  x  = image 
  
  Features = {}

  for name, layer in model._modules.items():
    x = layer(x)
    if name in layers:
      Features[layers[name]] = x

    return Features

content_f = get_features(content_p,vgg)
style_f = get_features(style_p,vgg)

def gram_matrix(tensor):
  b,c,h,w = tensor.size()
  tensor = tensor.view(c,h*w)
  gram = torch.mm(tensor,tensor.t())
  return gram 

style_grams = {layer: gram_matrix(style_f[layer]) for layer in style_f}

# Creating Style and Content loss fucntion

def content_loss(target_conv4_2, content_conv4_2):
  loss = torch.mean((target_conv4_2-content_conv4_2)**2)
  return loss

style_weights = {
    'conv1_1' : 1.0,
    'conv2_1' : 0.75,
    'conv3_1' : 0.2,
    'conv4_1' : 0.2,
    'conv5_1' : 0.2

}

def style_loss(style_weights,target_features,style_grams):
  loss = 0
  for layer in style_weights:
    target_f = target_features[layer]
    target_gram = gram_matrix(target_f)
    style_gram = style_gram[layer]
    b,c,h,w = target_f.shape 
    layer_loss = style_weights[layers]*torch.mean((target_gram-style_gram)**2)
    loss += layer_loss/(c*h*w)
    return loss

target = content_p.clone().requires_grad_(True).to(device)
target_f = get_features(target,vgg)


print("Content Loss : ",content_loss(target_f['conv4_2'],content_f['conv4_2']))
print("Style Loss : ",style_loss(style_weights, target_f , style_grams))
```

Output from last 2 line of code :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-3b32a5406c6a> in <module>()
----> 1 print("Content Loss : ",content_loss(target_f['conv4_2'],content_f['conv4_2']))
      2 print("Style Loss : ",style_loss(style_weights, target_f , style_grams))

KeyError: 'conv4_2'
```

I will be very thankful for a quick response !!
Please do let me know if anyone need any code related help for solving this question !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a standard `torchvision` VGG network, something like:

```
>>> vgg = torchvision.models.vgg16()
```

You're looking to access some convolutional layers in your `get_features` function. However, these layers are contained inside a sub-module, not the direct children (the ones you are accessing with the `_modules` attribute).
*Btw, you shouldn't be using this attribute, the underscore is meant to designate *private* attributes.*

```
>>> dict(vgg.named_children()).keys()
dict_keys(['features', 'avgpool', 'classifier'])
```

So here instead, you should be looking into `vgg.features`, *i.e.* the CNN section of VGG.

Then at this point your function does make sense, since you're indexing from the layer number in the convolution section of the model:

```
def get_features(x, model):
   layers = {'0' : 'conv1_1',
             '5' : 'conv2_1',
             '10': 'conv3_1',
             '19': 'conv4_1',
             '21': 'conv4_2',
             '28': 'conv5_1'}

   features = {}
   for name, layer in model.named_children():
      x = layer(x)
      if name in layers:
         features[layers[name]] = x.detach()

   return features
```

Then `features` will contain the following keys:

```
>>> features.keys()
dict_keys(['conv1_1', 'conv2_1', 'conv3_1', 'conv4_1', 'conv4_2', 'conv5_1'])
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [forward hooks](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/nnft_tutorial.html#forward-and-backward-function-hooks), this is in my opinion a much better solution. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985476/6331369) I explain in great detail how to implement such a method.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan, for your response i will implement it and then get back to you