# CNN feature Extraction

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

```
class ResNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, output_features, fine_tuning=False):
    super(ResNet, self).__init__()
    self.resnet152 = tv.models.resnet152(pretrained=True)
    
    #freezing the feature extraction layers
    for param in self.resnet152.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = fine_tuning
        
    #self.features = self.resnet152.features
    
    self.num_fts = 512
    self.output_features = output_features
    
    # Linear layer goes from 512 to 1024
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.num_fts, self.output_features)
    nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.classifier.weight)
    
    self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
    
def forward(self, x):
   
    h = self.resnet152(x)
    print('h:   ',h.shape)
  
    return h

image_model_resnet152=ResNet(output_features=10).to(device)
image_model_resnet152
```

Here, after printing the `image_model_resnet152`, I get:

[image]

Here, what is the difference between `(avgpool): Linear(in_features=2048)` 
and `(classifier): Linear(in_features=512)`?

I am implementing an image captioning model, so which `in_features` should I take for an image?

Comment: How was `ResNet` defined?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question. Would you mind checking once more?

Comment: Did you implement this module on your own? So, are you asking about the difference between an adaptive average pool layer and a fully connected layer?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented it previously using VGG16. There was a module named features and whenever I pass an image of shape [1,3,224,224] to the VGG16 model's features module. The module returned a vector of shape [1,512,7,7].  But now in Resnet152 there is no system like that so I am in now bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResNet is not as straightforward as VGG: it's not a sequential model, *i.e.* there is some model-specific logic inside the `forward` definition of the `torchvision.models.resnet152`, for instance, the flattening of features between the CNN and classifier. You can take a look at [its source code](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L144).

The easiest thing to do in this case is to add a hook on the last layer of the CNN: `layer4`, and log the result of that layer in an external *dict*. This is done with [`register_forward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.modules.module.register_module_forward_hook.html).

Define the hook:

```
out = {}
def result(module, input, output):
   out['layer4'] = output
```

Attach the hook on the submodule `resnet.layer4`:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(1,3,224,224)
>>> resnet = torchvision.models.resnet152()

>>> resnet.layer4.register_forward_hook(result)
```

After inference you will have access to the result inside of `out`:

```
>>> resnet(x)
>>> out['layer4']
(1, 2048, 7, 7)
```

You can look at [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985476/6331369) of mine on a more in-depth usage of forward hooks.

---

A possible implementation would be:

```
class NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resnet = torchvision.models.resnet152()
        self.resnet.layer4.register_forward_hook(result)
        self.out = {}
    
    @staticmethod
    def result(module, input, output):
        out['layer4'] = output

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.resnet(x)
        return out['layer4']
```

You can then define additional layers for your custom classifier and call them inside `forward`.

Comment: Thank you very very much!! This is a really broad and better explanation I have found on the internet. This will help me a lot.