# Is there an inbuilt function to print the output of each neuron of a CNN in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I created one CNN model with 4 convolutional layers. how to find the  number of neurons and output of the each layer

[CNN Architecture ]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XASaf.png)```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no builtin to output the size of each layers in a CNN.

There are however ways to inspect modules using forward hooks: [`nn.Module.register_forward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=register_forward#torch.nn.Module.register_forward_hook). One way is to prepare an empty dictionary before inference and feed the results via the hook callback.

Here is a minimal example using, construct a hook factory function:

```
get_parameter_count = lambda x: sum(p.numel() for p in x.parameters())

def create_hook(name, out):
    def hook(module, in_tensor, out_tensor):
        out[name] = get_parameter_count(module), out_tensor
    return hook
```

Now you can attach the custom hooks on the different layers of the module named `model`:

```
out = {}
for name, layer in model.named_children():
    layer.register_forward_hook(create_hook(name, out))
```

Finally we are ready to infer by calling `model`. The intermediate results and submodule sizes will be contained inside `out` *after inference*.

---

Here is a demo with the following class:

```
class DummyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.convs = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, 3), 
                                   nn.Conv2d(16, 8, 3, 3))
        self.pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(2)
        self.classif = nn.Linear(32, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.convs(x)
        out = self.pool(out)
        out = out.flatten(1)
        out = self.classif(out)
        return out
```

And the desired dictionary is constructed with the following:

```
>>> model = DummyNet()
>>> y = model(torch.rand(2, 3, 100, 100))

>>> for name, (c, y) in out.items():
...     print(f'[{name}] #parameter={c}, output shape={y[0].shape}')
[convs] #parameter=1608, output shape=(2, 8, 11, 11)
[pool] #parameter=0, output shape=(2, 8, 2, 2)
[classif] #parameter=330, output shape=(2, 10)
```

You can read more about forward hooks in another thread: [***How to get all the tensors in a graph?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878476/how-to-get-all-the-tensors-in-a-graph/65647597#65647597)