# How to get TensorFlow operations contained in Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a TensorFlow Keras model (TensorFlow 2.6.0); here's a basic example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = inp = tf.keras.Input((5,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inp, x)
```

I would like to get all the `tf.Operation` objects in the graph for the model, select specific operations, then create a new `tf.function` or `tf.keras.Model` to output the values of those tensors on arbitrary inputs.

For example, in my simple model above, I might want to get the outputs of all `relu` operators. I know in that case, I could redefine the model to include the output of that layer as another output of the model, but the point here is that I already have the model (it's much more complicated than above), and there are specific operators that I want to find to get the outputs of.

Comment: I have had some success with `model.make_predict_function()._concrete_stateful_fn.graph.get_operations()`. The problem is that the resulting tensors are now in the context of that function, and I don't know whether they can be used to create a new function that will output the values of those tensors for an arbitrary input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
all_ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
```

If you got an empty list and you use Tensorflow 2.x , you may try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() # disable eager execution

a = tf.constant([1],name='aa')
print(tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_operations())
print(tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('aa:0'))
```

Comment: Running `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_operations()` returns an empty list for me. Evidently, there is nothing in the model creation that makes any internal graphs the "default" graph.

Comment: I edit my answer

Comment: I would like to avoid turning off eager execution if possible, since it will make changes throughout my whole program. If there's not another way to do it, though, I may turn to it as a last resort.

Comment: Also, see my specific use-case as described in my original question. First of all, I'm using a `tf.keras.Model`, not just some stand-alone TensorFlow commands. Second, I need to be able to use the output tensors of the operations to create a new function that will give me those values for arbitrary inputs.

Comment: But you need first to get operations, for that reason you should divide your problem to two problems , you should solve the first , I mean you should get the ops of the graphs

Comment: But are all graphs amenable to being used in the way I want, to get those operation output tensor values? I've found another way to get a graph, but I haven't been able to use it to get tensor output values: `model.make_predict_function()._concrete_stateful_fn.graph.get_operations()`. In your example, how would I use that graph to get the output of one of the operations for a given input?

Comment: Did you see this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883949/in-tensorflow-get-the-names-of-all-the-tensors-in-a-graph

Comment: The other problem with using the default graph like this is that it appears that all `tf.keras.Model` objects that get created get added to the default graph. My code may have multiple models in it, which will make it hard to separate out the parts I want related to a specific model.